# php soap wsdl error on request header

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

```
$options = array('trace' => true);
$client = new SoapClient('http://topup.sparrowsms.com/wsdl/?wsdl' , $options);
$header = new SoapHeader('http://topup.sparrowsms.com/wsdl/?wsdl', 'RequestHeader', array("access_token"=>$token), true);
$params = new SoapHeader('http://topup.sparrowsms.com/wsdl/?wsdl', 'topup' , array('topup_request' => array('msisdn' => $number , 'amount' => $amount , 'requestRef' => 1)));
$client->__setSoapHeaders(array($header , $params));
echo "<pre>";print_r($client->__getTypes());echo "</pre>"; 
echo "<pre>";print_r($client->__getFunctions());echo "</pre>"; 
$response = $client->topup();
```

I have this error when calling  `$response = $client->topup();` I want to use topup at this time.

PHP sends this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [senv:1012] Invalid Access Token

Comment: `RequestHeader` is not part of the `TopupRequestModel` parameters. Take a look at your WSDL

Comment: Yes you are right but it's not my challenge i used to change my code